# Libre Ofice Calc - problem with looping formula

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with this problem (without changing text in cell):

```
B9=16,50
B10=B9-B11
B11=B10*2
```

I don't know how to stop looping this formula
Thank you in advance for help

Comment: B10 depends on result of B11 and vice versa. To stop looping the formula, either remove the reference to B11 in B10 or the reference to B10 in B11.

Comment: You have all right, but does exist a trick to see values in my cells? actually i have only error 523 (and i can't change nothing in cells, it's statement of question) . Answer is 16 , 11, 5.5. I tried to turn off iteration in option but it doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, your question is quite unclear. What's exactly the problem? Do you want to **(1)** remove the loop -> adapt one of the formulas in B10 or B11; **(2)** edit B10 ir B11 -> select cell, hit F2, change content. There's **no third option** "keep the loop, get rid of the error".

Comment: My lecturer want to 3 option... He didn't let me to change formulas in cell,  he want explanation error and "magic solve"...

Comment: OK, i see - you need the iteration ticked, or you'll get at 522 error. The documentation has a working example: https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/optionen/01060500.html?DbPAR=SHARED#bm_id3149399 but it won't work for factors >=1 multiplied with B10. I can't tell why, sorry...